# Ajax Json path not found

Tags: javascript, c++, ajax, webserver

I am not bad in C++ but I have a terrible knowledge about web so please consider that the answer to this question will be simple.

I have found a C++ library for a webserver [here on github](https://github.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server).

It works fine when I enter http://localhost:8080/ in my browser to test its HTML page. I also have tested:

```
http://localhost:8080/info
http://localhost:8080/match/8796
```

They work fine too.

However, when I try to test its Ajax/Json, it does not work for me using the following code in my firefox browser console.

```
$.post( "json", {firstName: "John",lastName: "Smith",age: 25} );



not well-formed     json:1:18  ---> Could not open path /json
```

I tried

```
$.post( "string", {firstName: "John",lastName: "Smith",age: 25} );
```

and received similar result.

Where am I doing mistake?

---

The C++ code in short, hosts a server on port 8080, responds to

```
server.resource["^/string$"]["POST"]
server.resource["^/json$"]["POST"]
server.resource["^/info$"]["GET"]
server.resource["^/work$"]["GET"]
server.default_resource["GET"]
```

The client examples are:

```
    //Client examples
    HttpClient client("localhost:8080");
    auto r1=client.request("GET", "/match/123");
    cout << r1->content.rdbuf() << endl;

    string json_string="{\"firstName\": \"John\",\"lastName\": \"Smith\",\"age\": 25}";
    auto r2=client.request("POST", "/string", json_string);
    cout << r2->content.rdbuf() << endl;

    auto r3=client.request("POST", "/json", json_string);
    cout << r3->content.rdbuf() << endl;
```

---

http_examples.cpp [[link]](https://github.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server/blob/master/http_examples.cpp)

```
#include "server_http.hpp"
#include "client_http.hpp"

//Added for the json-example
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

//Added for the default_resource example
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
//Added for the json-example:
using namespace boost::property_tree;

typedef SimpleWeb::Server<SimpleWeb::HTTP> HttpServer;
typedef SimpleWeb::Client<SimpleWeb::HTTP> HttpClient;

//Added for the default_resource example
void default_resource_send(const HttpServer &server, shared_ptr<HttpServer::Response> response,
                           shared_ptr<ifstream> ifs, shared_ptr<vector<char> > buffer);

int main() {
    //HTTP-server at port 8080 using 1 thread
    //Unless you do more heavy non-threaded processing in the resources,
    //1 thread is usually faster than several threads
    HttpServer server(8080, 1);

    //Add resources using path-regex and method-string, and an anonymous function
    //POST-example for the path /string, responds the posted string
    server.resource["^/string$"]["POST"]=[](shared_ptr<HttpServer::Response> response, shared_ptr<HttpServer::Request> request) {
        //Retrieve string:
        auto content=request->content.string();
        //request->content.string() is a convenience function for:
        //stringstream ss;
        //ss << request->content.rdbuf();
        //string content=ss.str();

        *response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << content.length() << "\r\n\r\n" << content;
    };

    //POST-example for the path /json, responds firstName+" "+lastName from the posted json
    //Responds with an appropriate error message if the posted json is not valid, or if firstName or lastName is missing
    //Example posted json:
    //{
    //  "firstName": "John",
    //  "lastName": "Smith",
    //  "age": 25
    //}
    server.resource["^/json$"]["POST"]=[](shared_ptr<HttpServer::Response> response, shared_ptr<HttpServer::Request> request) {
        try {
            ptree pt;
            read_json(request->content, pt);

            string name=pt.get<string>("firstName")+" "+pt.get<string>("lastName");

            *response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << name.length() << "\r\n\r\n" << name;
        }
        catch(exception& e) {
            *response << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Length: " << strlen(e.what()) << "\r\n\r\n" << e.what();
        }
    };

    //GET-example for the path /info
    //Responds with request-information
    server.resource["^/info$"]["GET"]=[](shared_ptr<HttpServer::Response> response, shared_ptr<HttpServer::Request> request) {
        stringstream content_stream;
        content_stream << "<h1>Request from " << request->remote_endpoint_address << " (" << request->remote_endpoint_port << ")</h1>";
        content_stream << request->method << " " << request->path << " HTTP/" << request->http_version << "<br>";
        for(auto& header: request->header) {
            content_stream << header.first << ": " << header.second << "<br>";
        }

        //find length of content_stream (length received using content_stream.tellp())
        content_stream.seekp(0, ios::end);

        *response <<  "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << content_stream.tellp() << "\r\n\r\n" << content_stream.rdbuf();
    };

    //GET-example for the path /match/[number], responds with the matched string in path (number)
    //For instance a request GET /match/123 will receive: 123
    server.resource["^/match/([0-9]+)$"]["GET"]=[&server](shared_ptr<HttpServer::Response> response, shared_ptr<HttpServer::Request> request) {
        string number=request->path_match[1];
        *response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << number.length() << "\r\n\r\n" << number;
    };

    //Get example simulating heavy work in a separate thread
    server.resource["^/work$"]["GET"]=[&server](shared_ptr<HttpServer::Response> response, shared_ptr<HttpServer::Request> /*request*/) {
        thread work_thread([response] {
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5));
            string message="Work done";
            *response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << message.length() << "\r\n\r\n" << message;
        });
        work_thread.detach();
    };

    //Default GET-example. If no other matches, this anonymous function will be called. 
    //Will respond with content in the web/-directory, and its subdirectories.
    //Default file: index.html
    //Can for instance be used to retrieve an HTML 5 client that uses REST-resources on this server
    server.default_resource["GET"]=[&server](shared_ptr<HttpServer::Response> response, shared_ptr<HttpServer::Request> request) {
        const auto web_root_path=boost::filesystem::canonical("web");
        boost::filesystem::path path=web_root_path;
        path/=request->path;
        if(boost::filesystem::exists(path)) {
            path=boost::filesystem::canonical(path);
            //Check if path is within web_root_path
            if(distance(web_root_path.begin(), web_root_path.end())<=distance(path.begin(), path.end()) &&
               equal(web_root_path.begin(), web_root_path.end(), path.begin())) {
                if(boost::filesystem::is_directory(path))
                    path/="index.html";
                if(boost::filesystem::exists(path) && boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(path)) {
                    auto ifs=make_shared<ifstream>();
                    ifs->open(path.string(), ifstream::in | ios::binary);

                    if(*ifs) {
                        //read and send 128 KB at a time
                        streamsize buffer_size=131072;
                        auto buffer=make_shared<vector<char> >(buffer_size);

                        ifs->seekg(0, ios::end);
                        auto length=ifs->tellg();

                        ifs->seekg(0, ios::beg);

                        *response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << length << "\r\n\r\n";
                        default_resource_send(server, response, ifs, buffer);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        string content="Could not open path "+request->path;
        *response << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Length: " << content.length() << "\r\n\r\n" << content;
    };

    thread server_thread([&server](){
        //Start server
        server.start();
    });

    //Wait for server to start so that the client can connect
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    //Client examples
    HttpClient client("localhost:8080");
    auto r1=client.request("GET", "/match/123");
    cout << r1->content.rdbuf() << endl;

    string json_string="{\"firstName\": \"John\",\"lastName\": \"Smith\",\"age\": 25}";
    auto r2=client.request("POST", "/string", json_string);
    cout << r2->content.rdbuf() << endl;

    auto r3=client.request("POST", "/json", json_string);
    cout << r3->content.rdbuf() << endl;

    server_thread.join();

    return 0;
}

void default_resource_send(const HttpServer &server, shared_ptr<HttpServer::Response> response,
                           shared_ptr<ifstream> ifs, shared_ptr<vector<char> > buffer) {
    streamsize read_length;
    if((read_length=ifs->read(&(*buffer)[0], buffer->size()).gcount())>0) {
        response->write(&(*buffer)[0], read_length);
        if(read_length==static_cast<streamsize>(buffer->size())) {
            server.send(response, [&server, response, ifs, buffer](const boost::system::error_code &ec) {
                if(!ec)
                    default_resource_send(server, response, ifs, buffer);
                else
                    cerr << "Connection interrupted" << endl;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested as the below steps and it runs flawlessly.

**Put this in a html file and run it from a browser:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.post( "http://localhost:8080/json", 
      JSON.stringify({ firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", age: 25 }) 
    );
</script>
```

**Change line #53's function of http_examples.cpp to this:**

```
server.resource["^/json$"]["POST"]=[](shared_ptr<HttpServer::Response> response, shared_ptr<HttpServer::Request> request) {
    try {
        ptree pt;
        read_json(request->content, pt);

        string name=pt.get<string>("firstName")+" "+pt.get<string>("lastName");

        *response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << name.length() << "\r\n" 
                  << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" << "\r\n\r\n" 
                  << name;
    }
    catch(exception& e) {
        *response << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Length: " << strlen(e.what()) << "\r\n\r\n" << e.what();
    }
};
```

**Then, recompile like this, and rerun:**

*Be sure to be in the project folder.*

```
make && ./http_examples
```

Comment: both of them respond `Could not open path /json`

Comment: Thanks. It works. I receive `syntax error` in console while in the response tab I see `John Smith`. I guess both `json` and `http` requests are working together.

Comment: @ar2015 yeah, it's probably because, server also needs to return http content type header as json

Comment: should we prevent it typically?

Comment: @ar2015 server should also return a header: ```Content-Type: application/json``` as I did with ```Accept-Control-Allow-Origin```. Just add this there. If that's what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the relative url by http://localhost:8080/json

Comment: I ran `$.post( "http://localhost:8080/json", {firstName: "John",lastName: "Smith",age: 25} );` and received `Could not open path /json`